# jQuery autocomplete on 500 error page

Tags: jquery

I need to make autocomplete for search field on 500 error page.
Autocomplete for this field on other pages works good, but on 500 error page i get nothing - no js error no autocomplete.

The question is: can i make autocomplete work on page whith http status code 500?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of for you to accomplish this would be to redirect 500 errors to another file using your `.htaccess`. This file could be customized however you see fit, including applying autocomplete to inputs.

Something like this in your `.htaccess` would work:

```
ErrorDocument 500 path/to/redirect/to.html
```